# Explanation of why duplicate entry is made on an upsert

Tags: mongodb

Assume I have this collection:

```
db.item.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5635194b6929067972b85c"),
    "name" : "car",
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "color" : "blue",
            "qty" : 10
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add a new entry into the embedded "attributes" document if it does not exist, otherwise only do the update. I constructed the following query to do this as per the MongoDb documentation:

```
db.item.update({"name":"car"}, {"$push" : {"attributes" : {"color": "red", "qty": 20}}}, upsert=true)
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

This works and I get this:

```
db.item.find({"name":"car"}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5635194b6929067972b85c"),
    "name" : "car",
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "color" : "blue",
            "qty" : 10
        },
        {
            "color" : "red",
            "qty" : 20
        }
    ]
}
```

However, if I run the query again, I get a duplicate entry added:

```
db.item.update({"name":"car"}, {"$push" : {"attributes" : {"color": "red", "qty": 20}}}, upsert=true)
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.item.find({"name":"car"}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5635194b6929067972b85c"),
    "name" : "car",
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "color" : "blue",
            "qty" : 10
        },
        {
            "color" : "red",
            "qty" : 20
        },
        {
            "color" : "red",
            "qty" : 20
        }
    ]
}
```

Why does that happen? The upsert should prevent this or am I misunderstanding the function of upsert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upsert is update or insert, if the matching document is present update will be done else insert.

In you case you already have a matching document, so update will be done. `$push` doesn't check for duplicates, you need to use `$addToSet`

If you want to avoid duplicates, you need to use `$addToSet`

```
db.item.update(
    {"name":"car"},
    {"$addToSet" : {"attributes" : {"color": "red", "qty": 20}}},
    {upsert:true}
)
```

result for second update

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```